# MaximumNumberOfRestartsWithinTimeRangeReached equivalent in Akka 2.0

Tags: akka, akka-supervision

In Akka 1.3.1, the supervisor received a `MaximumNumberOfRestartsWithinTimeRangeReached` message when the max restart limit was reached.

Is there something equivalent in Akka 2.0? I can get the Terminated message, but I wanted to be able to detect this particular error condition. `MaximumNumberOfRestartsWithinTimeRangeReached` also gave you the lastExceptionCausingRestart, which was useful.

Comment: Anybody have an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been replaced by a more elaborate definition of the
SupervisorStrategy() for a supervisor Actor.

As I understand, this also means the message does not any more arrive as a message in the onReceive()